# IndentationError in a class python

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

i hv code like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class OP(object):

  def RECEIVE_MESSAGE(self):
      print("done")


  def NOTIFIED_INVITE_INTO_GROUP(self):
    print("done")
```

but when i run this i got some error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
  from van import ERVAN
File "/home/server/.pub/van.py", line 4, in <module>
  from op import OP
File "/home/server/.pub/op.py", line 9
  def NOTIFIED_INVITE_INTO_GROUP(self):
                                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

any solution for this? its just 10 lines but blowing my mind

Comment: In your code looks like the first function has four spaces indentation and the second only two. If you pasted it from your file, and did not make a typo here, this could be the problem.

Comment: you can use "tab" too, is basically 4 spaces and no need to count the spaces (this is how I use and is most compatible with the code even from py2.7)

Comment: But in Python 3+ you're not allowed to mix spaces and tabs - so choose one or the other and stick to it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your code with spaces replaced by dots:

```
#.-*-.coding:.utf-8.-*-

class.OP(object):

..def.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(self):
......print("done")

..def.NOTIFIED_INVITE_INTO_GROUP(self):
....print("done")
```

As you can see, the first `print("done")` statement is indented by 6 spaces - change it to 4 to fix the problem.

Better still, change all indents so they are multiples of 4 spaces (ie 0, 4, 8, 12 etc), as recommended by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

```
#.-*-.coding:.utf-8.-*-

class.OP(object):
....def.RECEIVE_MESSAGE(self):
........print("done")

....def.NOTIFIED_INVITE_INTO_GROUP(self):
........print("done")
```

More detail, from [Python: Myths about Indentation](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)

> **How does the compiler parse the indentation?** The parsing is
>   well-defined and quite simple. Basically, changes to the indentation
>   level are inserted as tokens into the token stream.
>
> The lexical analyzer (tokenizer) uses a stack to store indentation
>   levels. At the beginning, the stack contains just the value 0, which
>   is the leftmost position. Whenever a nested block begins, the new
>   indentation level is pushed on the stack, and an "INDENT" token is
>   inserted into the token stream which is passed to the parser. There
>   can never be more than one "INDENT" token in a row.
>
> When a line is encountered with a smaller indentation level, values
>   are popped from the stack until a value is on top which is equal to
>   the new indentation level (**if none is found, a syntax error occurs**).

Comment: also per PEP8 naming convention: Function name should be lowercase.

Comment: no problem - don't forget, you can 'accept' an answer by clicking the green checkbox - that will encourage others to help you with your next question :)